# Why some methods cannot be called with Rounded bracket in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is the example. I would like to know why I am not able to use Rounded Bracket  (`()`)  to call the `toFloat` method

**This works** : `toFloat`

```
scala> val no = "8.5".toFloat
no: Float = 8.5
```

This **DO NOT work** : `toFloat()`

```
scala> val no = "8.5".toFloat()
<console>:27: error: Float does not take parameters
         val no = "8.5".toFloat()
                               ^
```

Comment: See http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions#parentheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`StringLike.toFloat`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringLike@toFloat:Float) is defined as:

```
def toFloat: Float = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(toString)
```

The documentation says the following in regards to parenthesis:

> ### Parentheses
>
> Unlike Ruby, Scala attaches significance to whether or not a method is declared with parentheses (only applicable to methods of arity-0).
>
> For example:
>
> `def foo1() = ...`
>
> `def foo2 = ...`
>
> These are different methods at compile-time. **While  foo1 can be called with or without the parentheses, foo2 may not be called with parentheses.**

This goes to show that if a method is declared *without parenthesis* they may not be added during invocation.